# Clustering Category Purchases in Customer Data

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, svd

I am attempting to cluster a group of customers based on spend, order frequency, order breadth and what % of purchases they make in each category (there are around 20).

It will probably be a simple answer but I cannot figure out whether I should standardize (subtract mean and divide by sd) the % category buy columns or not. When I dont standardize I can get around 90% of the variance explained in 4-5 principal components (using SVD), but when I standardize each column I only get around 40% for the same number of principal components. My worry is that because each column is related, I am removing the relationship by standardizing. At the same time I am worried that not standardizing will cause issues with the other variables in the data that I have standardized.

I would assume if others tried clustering in this way they would face a similar issue but I cant seem to find one so it might be that I just dont understand the situation. Thanks for any clarification in advance!

Chris,

Answer (score 0):

Percentage scale has a well defined range and nice properties.

By heuristically scaling these features you usually make things worse.